# Vedas, Ramayana, Mahabharata, Puranas and the Science

Tags: ancient-history, india, science

For someone who is born in India, some of the few mythological stories we watch on tv/hear from our grandparents are Ramayana, excerpts from Mahabharata or other Vedic stories of gods,  the vedic way of life/afterlife etc etc... Well as a kid, I really liked them. But now, thinking about them, I feel all the stories make sense. There are proofs that the Ramayana and the Mahabharata really happened. I am not going to dwell on the proof's part.

putting this aside, we also have [vedic science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_science), vedic mathematics, [vedic metric systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_measurement), [vedic cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_cosmology), [astronomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_astronomy), yugas, [evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_views_on_evolution), ayurveda(medicine) the list keeps going on. You name it, we have it way earlier than the rest of the world actually knew what it was. It looks like we(the Indian history) almost have a perfect and complex system for everything we need. But most of them wouldn't believe all this especially in the western world.

So everything is like a story perfectly laid out for people to read about their history and learn science in the process. But, I feel there's something missing for all of this to actually believe. So I guess my question is whats the missing part ? why did Indians just leave behind all the science and technology they had ? why isn't the knowledge of the Vedas carried to the modern India ?

Comment: There was a lot of war between the Vedic age and now, and all of the nations of the time fell and were replaced millennia ago. War and the fall of empires tends to cause a lot of knowledge to be lost and have to be recovered from ancient texts or rediscovered anew.

Comment: What is the question here? I'm confused.

Comment: Is there an inherent assumption that there was a lot of science and technology during the Vedic age? If so, what science and technology? References should be actually conforming to what modern science says. The references you have provided are pseudo science and linguistics. As regards astronomy, the wiki page is only a historical account without any of the science itself- so I can't tell if it conforms to today's astronomy views. Evolution- pseudo science and theology again- not science. And yes- what's the question again?

Comment: @Rajib: The earth is in spherical shape and revolving around sun. There are seven colors in sun light. The first surgery in the history. The study of blood circulation in human body. Study of atoms. Arithmetic progressions and geometric progressions. Travelling of sunlight. The definition of Gravity and many more...If this is theology and pseudo-science then what is the definition of science?

Answer (score 7):

This is my personal opinion, but in an age where not all people were literate and much of the available knowledge was unwritten, much of it could be easily lost. For example, the artisans and craftsmen of ancient India would not write about their knowledge anywhere. Instead, knowledge was transmitted from generation-to-generation using the spoken word. This meant that much of the information developed could be easily lost in case of upheavels such as invasions, etc.

Comment: If we forget about whats lost, whats wrong with the one's that been passed from generations ??

Comment: +2 or more if I could. I'm a strong informationalist (if that's a word) about history myself, so citing the retention and transmission of knowledge as prime factor is always good for a +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Just my opinion but, the Ramayana, while a fascinating look into India's past and our ancestors concept of relationships between men and women, should not be taken as a literal means of living one's life.  There are certainly noble concepts in the story pertaining to self-sacrifice and living to honor others, but realistically the idea of women being lowly subjugated partners to their husbands is deeply offensive.  Sita is hardly better than a slave or farm animal.

Neat story, but just because it's old doesn't mean I should revere it as infallible.

Comment: "Infallibility" is not the claim the OP is making- he says it really happened. Any "proof" of that must be some jingoistic nonsense from some faith group. The Mahabharata and the Ramayana are JUST stories- like you say.

Comment: As an Indian, I can say, people in India see Sita as their mother, and respect Her than any other women. Women in India want a man like SreenRama to be her husband. The moral values in these  puranas and stories is the base of Indian culture. In a particular month, Ramayana is read in most of the Indian houses and explains it to children and family members. Those stories make Indian Child aware about the good and bad in the world. They learn to respect their elders like Rama did. And ultimately they learn to stand for moral values of their country.

Comment: @AskingStory- you do not speak for all Indians and certainly exhibit a deep bias. Your proclamations regarding India give us a bad name and paint us like bumbling idiots from the 18th century. Grow up and desist from passionate rhetoric and make-believe on History SE.

Comment: @Rajib: It's just my opinion about this answer which is based on pure misunderstanding of one of the greatest epics in our history. I can't really agree with this answer. "Sita is hardly better than slave or farm animal"??and you agreed that these are just stories. With all due respect, I just disagree sir.

Comment: "Sita is hardly better than a slave or farm animal." No this is merely your biased opinion. Can you cite any instance where she is hardly better than a slave or farm animal? In my opinion it is far more regressive that you are just told that you are going to carry a so-called son of god in your womb with least bit caring about the woman's opinion. And this is just one example.

Comment: @Rajib: "The Mahabharata and the Ramayana are JUST stories". Do you have any evidence for that clam? Or you just assume that biblical myths are only real history and earth was created 6000 years ago?

Comment: @RolenKoh No I don't believe in the biblical stories either. There are other stackexchange forums for Hinduism, Christianity, religions, myths etc. This one is about history. While total objectivity is never possible in history, we'll go by what is accepted evidentially. That means evolution. WRT Ramayana, there are at least 50 versions with various interpretations, and these are accepted as stories. If someone claims this is history (reality that happened) the onus is on that claim maker to prove it.

Comment: @Rajib: So what? Many versions of life story's of famous personalities are there. And only Valmiki Ramayan is considered to be the authentic one. Besides Luke, Mark, Matthew and John gave different accounts of Jesus' life and his punishment so he might as well be imaginary or you give special exemption to that case?

Comment: @RolenKoh long discussions are discouraged here. I have already stated I don't believe in the Bible/biblical stories.  As regards Valmiki Ramayan being authentic, all are equally fictitious. Again, this is History stackexchange- not mythology. Refrain from discussing in comments.